# Is there a way to fix admin privledges once and for all?

Tags: administrator

This is driving me mad. I am on a Mac OSX 10.6.8. I have been to the info box and given myself read and write privileges.  I am the sole owner of my computer,  yet I get told that I do not have admin privileges when I try to change things.  For instances I am trying to update Ruby in my Terminal and am told I do not have write permission.  I DO have write permission.  I AM the admin.  It is crazy and I am pulling my hair out.  I have searched all over and cannot seem to find out how to fix this.  Can someone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Your operating system is important for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a security measure to prevent other software you may execute from modifying the system without your knowledge.  Prefix an administrative command with `sudo` and you'll be prompted to enter your password.  After that the command will execute with elevated privileges necessary to modify system files/settings.

Answer (score 1):

Like soandos said, the operating system matters a lot here.

But I can point out that most modern OS's (unix based systems do this routinely, but Windows makes some use of it too) can run a process at less than full privileges for security reasons.  So, if you are using something like a terminal window, the priveleges for the process can be just as significant as the priveleges for the user account.